Implementing SharedMergeTree in clickhouse-sqlalchemy
I am new to using Clickhouse Cloud and currently I'm adding support for it in my Python repository using Sqlalchemy. I've noticed that the SharedMergeTree engine is not supported in clickhouse-sqlalchemy, whereas most of the tables I've created directly on Clickhouse, have the SharedMergeTree engine. I need to know if there is a way to use SharedMergeTree in clickhouse-sqlalchemy somehow or should I stick to creating tables directly on Clickhouse cloud and not use clickhouse-sqlalchemy? I mainly need sqlalchemy for managing tables like migrations and stuff. Will be writing raw queries in any case because of better performance.
class AddToCart(ClickhouseBase):
    __tablename__ = 'add_to_cart'
    __table_args__ = (
        engines.MergeTree(),
        {'schema': 'default'},
    )

    event_type = mapped_column(String, primary_key=True)
    user = mapped_column(String)
    metadata = mapped_column(String)


You should be able to simply use a MergeTree - this will automatically be translated to a SharedMergeTree by clickhouse cloud transparently.
